# How to change Material-UI MenuItem background on hover change?

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, hover

was trying to change the material-ui MenuItem background color on hover change. was wondering what a good way to achieve it is.

For examples for a Select of

```
<Select
  value={this.state.age}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  inputProps={{
    name: "age",
    id: "age-simple"
  }}
 >
   <MenuItem value="">
     <em>None</em>
   </MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

and make it like

[image]

Answer (score 4):

was able to achieve it by using

```
menuItem: {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#009900 !important"
    }
  }
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-gg9ll?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: any idea how to this on nativeselect ?